# while using two scatter plot charts in one webpage the legends are adding up showing only in the second scatter chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

in d3.js while using 2 scatterplot in same webpage the legends of both the graph are being mixed and showing up in one graph.

here's the code

this is the code from first scatter plot

```
    // draw legend
  var legen1 = sc.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
   });

   // draw legend colored rectangles
  legen1.append("rect")
    .attr("x", width - 18)
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", color);

   // draw legend text
  legen1.append("text")
    .attr("x", width - 24)
    .attr("y", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text(function(d) { return d;})
```

this is the code form second scatter plot

```
   // draw legend
  var legen2 = tper.selectAll(".legend")
     .data(color.domain())
   .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 +    ")"; });

   // draw legend colored rectangles
 legen2.append("rect")
     .attr("x", width - 18)
     .attr("width", 18)
   .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", color);

 // draw legend text
 legen2.append("text")
    .attr("x", width - 24)
    .attr("y", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text(function(d) { return d;})
```

I changed the variable name even you can see its legen1,legen2 but still the prob exists.Here's the photo attached which clearly shows 21 legends but the graph only has 10 legends... the extra legends are of first graph

[image]

Comment: `legen1` and `legen2` are both still targeting `".legend"`... change the class name too.

Comment: did that too but no change seen?

Comment: The reason is here color.domain() ... console(color.domain()) and you will see all your legend values that is displayed you need to fix that.

Comment: thx man @Cyril your solution worked, i just changed the variable names so as to differ there domains.... i.e. for fist chart `.style("fill",color1);` and similarly for second one `.style("fill",color2);` and just declared separate variables above in the code